# jQuery UI datepicker highlight adjacent day

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I am building reservation system and I want to use jQuery UI datepicker with plugin http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/. When user select some date, I need to highlight also adjacent date of selected (add class to it, but not select it) and remove class when user deselect date. Does anyone have some ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the beforeShowDay options for the jQuery UI datepicker: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay.

I think you could achive what your after by getting the selected dates via the getDates( format, type ) method and then just check if the day you are about to show is adjacent to one in the array of dates you are getting from getDates( format, type )